# Show that $f$ gets a global minimum and a global maximum on $D$

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ and $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=3x^2-2xy+3y^2$.

(a) Show that $f$ gets a global minimum and a global maximum on $D$.

(b) Determine all points on $D$ where $f$ gets its global minimum and global maximum.

$$$$

For question (b) first I found the critical points on the boundary of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ using  Lagrange multipliers. Then I determined the critical points of $f(x,y)$ for the interior of the circle. Then combining all results I foundthe global minimum and the global maximum.

But how can we show (a) ? Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

**Continuous** function attains maximum and minimum on a **compact** set.

You just have to verify that your problem satisfies these properties.

Comment: The function is continuous as a polynomial. A set is compact if it is closed and bounded, right? The set $D$ is bounded because $D$ is the set of points on and inside a circle, right? Is $D$ for the same reason also compact?

Comment: you just have to further explain why is the set closed.

Comment: A closed set is a set whose complement is an open set. The complement of $D$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, right?

Comment: The complement is $x^2+y^2 >1$.

Comment: Is this set open because we have a strict inequality? @copper.hat

Comment: @MaryStar If $g$ is a continuous function and $U$ is an open set, then $g^{-1}(U)$ is open. (The same applies with the word open replaced in both places by closed). Here the set $U=(1,\infty)$ is open and $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Why is the set of $x^2+y^2>1$ equal to $(1,\infty)$ ? @copper.hat

Comment: @MaryStar I did not say that, it is clearly not equal. It is $g^{-1}((1,\infty))$.

Comment: Ah you mean that $>1$ is represented by the set $(1,\infty)$ ? @copper.hat

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. You could also note that $g^{-1}([0,1]) = D$ which is a little more direct. Since $g$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ closed then so is $D$.

Comment: $[0,1]$ is closed because in $\mathbb{R}$ a closed set is a closed interval, i.e .an interval where the boundaries are included, right? @copper.hat

Comment: @MaryStar I do not know what definitions you are using. I would say it is closed because the complement is open.

Comment: Ok! Is the justification that $D$ is bounded correct and complete? "The set $D$ is bounded because $D$ is the set of points on and inside a circle, i.e. all points satisfythe inequality $x^2+y^2\leq 1$".@copper.hat

Comment: @MaryStar I am not sure what your last comment means. You can show that $D$ is compact. One way is to show closed and bounded.

Comment: Yes, to show that $D$ is bounded do we justify that as follows? The set $D$ is bounded because $D$ is the set of points on and inside a circle, i.e. all points satisfythe inequality $x^2+y^2\leq 1$@copper.hat

Comment: @MaryStar These are things you should probably know! $D$ is bounded because there is some $B$ such that $\|(x,y)\| \le B$ for all $(x,y) \in D$.